# WindowsCE alernative to LogonUser function?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ce

I Need to test if a local NTLM User with the given credentials exits (& password does match). In Win NT I can do this with the LogonUser API. How can I archieve the same on a WindowsCE platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to create the NTLM security contexts for the client and the server using `AcquireCredentialsHandle`.  It's not as simple as calling `LogonUser`, but it's fairly straightforward.  [There's a complete (and too long to repost here) example here](http://blog.opennetcf.com/2005/02/08/ntlm-domain-authentication-in-ce/).

Comment: This sample is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!